# Is it possible to pass user/pass in solr collection url

Tags: javascript, solr, solrj, solrcloud, solr4

I created a solr service and blocked public access to url by adding user authentication.

http://username:password@example.com:8983/solr/ working fine in mozilla browser. Is this a proper method to pass user name and password to access collection from my javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the user library, it will probably work just fine. Most http libraries and those available by default in modern javascript supports the syntax.

Comment: Thanks , I my case this code will work on all browers. Is there any alternate method to pass username and password with javascript

Comment: i created users by editing security.json. after adding this when i am selecting data it is asking user authentication through browser and via javascript. I need to avoid this by passing username and password . Can u help on this

Comment: If you can't authenticate in your browser when navigating to the page, it won't work through javascript either. Make sure to fix that issue first - there might be something wrong with your configuration/user/password/etc.

Comment: i am able to authenticate when navigating to the page. Issue facing in http://username:password@example.com:8983/solr/books/select/?json.wrf=getIt&rows=10&wt=json&q=id:1 .  I need to pass username and password to collection url .

Comment: That should be done in exactly the same way. Make sure that the user you're using has a role with the correct access to the collection.